# Getting Error: Parse error on line 1: < script type = "app ^ Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'

Tags: json-ld

I've looked at several threads and can't figure out why I'm getting the error mentioned in the subject line. I've checked quote marks (") and commas (,). What is causing this?

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "BlogPosting",
  "mainEntityOfPage": {
    "@type": "WebPage",
    "@id": "https://www.stand8.io/insights/case-study-uat-automation-improves-coverage-with-auditable-results"
  },
  "headline": "How UAT Automation Improves Coverage With Auditable Results",
  "image": "https://www.stand8.io/static/032c98f33798e1d79227069fd9dcec1b/f10a9/STAND8_RGB.png",  
  "author": {
    "@type": "Organization",
    "name": "STAND 8",
    "url": "https://www.stand8.io/"
  },  
  "publisher": {
    "@type": "Organization",
    "name": "STAND 8",
    "logo": {
      "@type": "ImageObject",
      "url": "https://www.stand8.io/"
    }
  },
  "datePublished": "2022-09-27"
}
</script>
```

> Parse error on line 1: < script type = "app ^ Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'

Comment: Not clear where you are getting this error, but did you try with just the JSON part, starting with `{`, without the HTML part (the `<script ...>` and `</script>` enclosing)?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, unfortunately, it didn't work. I got it from a Schema Markup generator, Merkle, and it validates on that site, but not in the editor. It does need "ld+json". Odd...

Comment: Nothing wrong with the markup. It's a long shot, but could it be to do with the copy/paste from that site? I'd an issue a few years ago with sample code copied from a webpage that turned out to contain some sort of invisible characters. (Perfectly legitimate site, it just had odd formatting), I eventually worked it out by manually deleting and replacing every single space which removing the offending characters I couldn't see.  Might be worth a try?

Comment: Thank you, will try!

Comment: What software is giving your this error?  Is this from a browser? Is it from a command line application?  Is it from a web based validation tool?  Without knowing the context, in which you are getting this error, it is very hard to advise you.

Comment: It's in Contentful CMS. We need to add schema to our blog posts for SEO. Merkle SEO validated it, JSONLint did not, Contentful did not.

Comment: JSONLint excepts JSON I guess, hence my advice above and the error message is really one of a JSON parser, hence expecting things to start with like `{` , not start with `<script`...

Comment: I've looked at a few other schema markup generators and they all start with 
<script type="application/ld+json">

Comment: @PatrickMevzek yes it was the script tags. Thank you!

Comment: On our site, GatsyJS populates the script tag, so it isn't needed.